# Measure the memory usage of an UIImage array

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I am implementing a custom control to present images, and that control uses an array to store either a `UIImage` or `NSString` object. I want to implement such a kind of mechanism:if the memory usage is high, the control will write some big `UIImage` objects into files, then replace the `UIImage` objects with their corresponding files path(`NSString` objects).

So the only question is how to mesure the memory usage of an `UIImage`? Thanks!

Comment: this is generally the wrong approach for this high abstraction layer (`UIImage`). `UIImage` may perform caching and purging in low memory scenarios -- all without your intervention. it's better to load only what you really need and use appropriately sized representations. you might be amazed at how few images an app really truly needs in memory, and how many some apps load into memory at once.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I know how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your code utilizes a memory portion that generates problem for the ios it calls the `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` method. so the conversion part you'll have to do in this method.

Comment: Thanks! But it would be too late for my case. You know, to save `UIImage` object into file, we need to convert it to `NSData` object first, which is very memory consuming, it may lead the app crash when doing such operation in `-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`